# exporting data from excel to access database

Tags: excel, vba, database, export

I need to transfer to access excel rows with 1000+ columns and I've found this code below:

```
    Sub ExcelToAccess()

'Declare variables
Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim dbFileName As String
Dim dbRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim xRow As Long, xColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

'Go to the worksheet containing the records you want to transfer.
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

'Determine the last row of data based on column A.
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Create the connection to the database.
Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection

'Define the database file name
dbFileName = "C:\YourFilePath\Database1.accdb"

'Define the Provider and open the connection.
With dbConnection
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbFileName & _
";Persist Security Info=False;"
.Open dbFileName
End With

'Create the recordset
Set dbRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
dbRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseServer
dbRecordset.Open Source:="Table1", _
ActiveConnection:=dbConnection, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable

'Loop thru rows & columns to load records from Excel to Access.
'Assume row 1 is the header row, so start at row 2.
For xRow = 2 To LastRow
dbRecordset.AddNew
'Assume this is an 8-column (field) table starting with column A.
For xColumn = 1 To 8
dbRecordset(Cells(1, xColumn).Value) = Cells(xRow, xColumn).Value
Next xColumn
dbRecordset.Update
Next xRow

'Close the connections.
dbRecordset.Close
dbConnection.Close

'Release Object variable memory.
Set dbRecordset = Nothing
Set dbConnection = Nothing

'Optional:
'Clear the range of data (the records) you just transferred.
'Range("A2:H" & LastRow).ClearContents

End Sub
```

The problem is that even for 8 columns, it only enters data to the second column for each row, leaving the rest with zeros.

For example, if I enter an excel row that contains 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 , the table1 in access always has
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0.

Can't seem to find a solution. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Save the excel data as CSV then open in Access. And won't Access open an excel file directly?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a very complex system based in excel and I need to do that indirectly from excel vba

Comment: Access has a limit of 255 fields in a table, so you won't be able to import 1000 columns.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you- Maybe I'll have to break the columns in 4 tables then

Comment: You would be far better creating a proper normalized table structure rather than trying to deal with the data as a flat file.

Comment: @RDreamer,, code needs only one correction,, `1 To 8` should `1 To 1000` since you sheet has 1000 columns. Rest code is fine and has to work.